# postsharp MethodInterceptionAspect can't be applied on interface method

Tags: postsharp

I've updated my project from 2.x version to 3.x version of Postsharp.

Now, VS are dumping me that:

MethodInterceptionAspect can't be applied on a interface method...
Could you help me about that...?

My aspect wants to intercep Isession.Close method of NHibernate.Isession.
  In postsharp 2.x all runs very fine, however, on 3.x version, postsharp warning me a error compiler.

I'll appreciate a lot your help.
  Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit this page... [http://doc.postsharp.net/composition][1]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This incompatibility was fixed in PostSharp versions 3.1.52 and 4.0.32 and should be now possible.